# How to send a Soap Request in JMeter to a WCF Service - Getting Bad Request 400 Error

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have this following WCF Service Operation:

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName="IDocumentGenerator")]
    public interface IDocumentGenerator
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "GenerateDocument")]
        XmlDocument GenerateDocument(int TemplateId, string Format, XmlDocument Payload);
    }
```

I can load the WSDL in the browser by navigating to the service. But, when I am sending a "SOAP/XML-RPC Request" in Jmeter to the same servie, I am receiving the Response Code - 400 - Bad Request.

Following is the Soap message I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GenerateDocument>
            <Format>Pdf</Format>
            <TemplateId>6</TemplateId>
            <Payload><a></a></Payload>
        </GenerateDocument>     
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlDocument will not get supported in WCF as an Operation parameter directly. You need to use the XmlSerializerFormat in the OperationContract attribute:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "GenerateDocument"), XmlSerializerFormat]
```

The Soap request I created was also not valid. For creating a Soap request, we can use the software from `http://www.soapui.org/`. After creating a valid Soap request, I was able to resolve the issue:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GenerateDocument>
         <tem:TemplateId>2</tem:TemplateId><tem:Format>2</tem:Format>
         <!--Optional:-->

         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Payload>
            <a/>
         </tem:Payload>
      </tem:GenerateDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```